# Subtract slice from slice of the same pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say we have

```
In [0]: df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [3, 4, 5]})
In [1]: df
Out[2]: 
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
2     3     5
```

What I need is to subtract `df[:-1]` from `df[1:]` and get a dataframe as a result, like this:

```
Out[3]: 
   col1  col2
0   1.0   1.0
1   1.0   1.0
```

But of course I'm getting

```
Out[11]: 
   col1  col2
0   NaN   NaN
1   0.0   0.0
2   NaN   NaN
```

I've tried using `iloc` for slicing, but got the same result. I'm aware of `df.values`, but I need a dataframe as a result.

Comment: `df.diff().dropna()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) and remove first `NaN`s row by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1 = df.diff().iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
   col1  col2
0   1.0   1.0
1   1.0   1.0
```

Another solution is subtract numpy arrays with `DataFrame` contructor:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df[1:].values - df[:-1].values, columns=df.columns)
print (df1)
   col1  col2
0     1     1
1     1     1
```